# Python equivalent of the OSHI library

Tags: library, python, cross-platform, hardware, operating-system

I am looking for the Python equivalent of the [Operating System & Hardware Information (OSHI)](https://github.com/oshi/oshi) Java library. This Python package or library must be cross-platform and can be used to get the following information from the host machine:

- A universally unique identifier (UUID) based on an underlying hardware ID that cannot be easily changed, rather than a MAC address
- The operating system and its version
- Network interfaces
- Physical memory size

There are ways to get these types of information in Python, but they involve a variety of different packages and OS-specific commands; I am looking for a one-stop shop like OSHI, a single cross-platform library or package that has predefined methods to return all of the above information. Does such a solution exist for Python? If not, is there something close to it?

Comment: I think the close to it method is combining the multiple ways in place already